# SQL CE Show Columns analog?

Tags: sql-server-ce

MySql has "show columns" statement which returns a table with column names, data types and other information. How to get the same information for SQL CE database tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve a fair bit of info using the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174156%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) views. These are in fact meant to be standard across database systems.